# Postgresql: insert with nested select and NEXTVAL in sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sought and not found the answer to this problem:

I insert a row using nested select but also need the uid sequence and datestamp

SQL insert

```
 insert into countdegreejob   (countdegreeid,jobid,uniquejobid,  id, created, updated) 

 select (cjtbdn.countdegreeid, j.id, j.uniquejobid ) NEXTVAL('hibernate_sequence'), now(), now()
 from job j 

 right join job_areasofstudy jd on j.id = jd.job_id

 inner join countjobtitlebydegreename cjtbdn on j.uniquejobid=cjtbdn.uniquejobid 

 where cjtbdn.degreename = jd.areasofstudy and jd.job_id is not NULL
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
>   LINE 2: ...jtbdn.countdegreeid, j.id, j.uniquejobid ) NEXTVAL('hibernat...

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the parentheses and adding a comma:

```
select cjtbdn.countdegreeid, j.id, j.uniquejobid, NEXTVAL('hibernate_sequence'), now(), now()
```

When you enclose columns in parentheses, you are telling Postgres that you want a record format.  So, these are not the same:

```
select 1, 2
select (1, 2)
```

The first returns two columns.  The second returns one column which happens to be a record with two fields.  I doubt any of the columns in your tables are actually records.

Wait.  That insert doesn't make full sense.  You are inserting 6 columns but have only 5 in the `insert` list.  What do you really want to do?

Comment: that was a typo. there should be an "id" in there

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `,` before `NEXTVAL` as below

```
select (cjtbdn.countdegreeid, j.id, j.uniquejobid )  NEXTVAL('hibernate_sequence'),
                                                   ^..... Here
```

Also those parenthesis `()` in `select` are not required

Comment: Actually the parentheses are not only "not required", they are plain wrong. `(cjtbdn.countdegreeid, j.id, j.uniquejobid)` is a **single** column (a record with three fields). `cjtbdn.countdegreeid, j.id, j.uniquejobid` are three columns.